# Is there an "official" name to the 0.0.0.0 IP address?

Tags: ip, ip-address

As 127.0.0.1 is known as the loopback address, is there a shorter term to refer to 0.0.0.0 other than "the IP address who means all IP address on local machine"?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Sometimes it is called "wildcard address", `INADDR_ANY`, or ["unspecified address"](https://serverfault.com/questions/228629/is-there-an-official-name-to-the-0-0-0-0-ip-address/228638#228638). The official name is "source address for this host on this network" ([RFC 5735, Section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5735#section-3)). It must not appear in packets sent to the network under normal circumstances:

> This host on this network.  MUST NOT
> be sent, except as
> a source address as part of an initialization procedure
> by which the host learns its own IP address.

But if it appears as destination address in incoming packet it should be treated as broadcast address 255.255.255.255 ([RFC 1122, Section 3.3.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1122#page-66))

Answer (score 17):

The official name for 0.0.0.0/0 (or ::0/0) is "the unspecified address".

Comment: Per @BMDan's answer, `/0` is different from `/32`.

Answer (score 10):

IPv4 `0.0.0.0/0` and IPv6 `::0/0`

- is "all addresses"
- covers every IP on the Internet
- is used in routing when specifying a default gateway
- is used firewalls when specifying default rules

is diferent from

`0.0.0.0/32` (is the same as `0.0.0.0`)

- `INADDR_ANY`
- is primarily used when accepting all incoming connections (regardless of the destination IP address or receiving network interface)
- "the unspecified address"
- is used on application-level as uninitialized IP address