# When using netstat on a listening port what is the difference between localhost:6666 and [::]:6666 in 'Local Address' field

Tags: linux, networking, localhost, netstat

Using ubuntu 11.04, I  run netstat -nplt  the results for  local address  may be

```
localhost:6666
```

or

```
[::]:6666
```

What  is  the  difference?

I  believe  that  the  [::]: binds  the  service at  port xxxx to all interfaces, (lo, eth0, eth1 ) and  localhost: only  binds it to loopback interface (lo). I  think I  am missing something. How  can I toggle  between the  two states?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[::] is an ipv6 notation and it's the same as 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000 , and it means any ip address.

Comment: does this server the  same function as 0.0.0.0 in ipv4? Bind  to all interfaces?

Comment: Does  it bind to ip addresses or interfaces

Comment: Yes, it's bind to all ip address, so all interfaces

Comment: Found  a good explanation here:  http://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1

Answer (score 4):

> localhost:6666

This is the IPv4 loopback address 127.0.0.1

> [::]:6666

This means port 6666 on all IP addresses (v4 and v6).