# Which one is better to query from - loopback-ip or interface-ip?

Tags: memcache, loopback

I have memcache server listing on 0.0.0.0:11211. I have to query the memcached server from the same box. Which one do you think is better: querying from 127.0.0.1:11211 or from interface-ip:11211. Please explain why also ?

Comment: See [What's the difference between ip address 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1?](http://serverfault.com/q/78048/126632)

Comment: I know the difference . What i meant is which one better , querying 127.0.0.1 or interface-ip ?

Answer (score 1):

> I have to query the memcached server from the same box.

Why not use Unix socket to avoid TCP/IP overhead:

```
$ memcached -h
memcached 1.2.8
repcached 2.2
-p <num>      TCP port number to listen on (default: 11211)
-U <num>      UDP port number to listen on (default: 11211, 0 is off)
-s <file>     unix socket path to listen on (disables network support)
```

See also: [Unix domain sockets vs TCP Sockets](https://web.archive.org/web/20170426091331/http://bhavin.directi.com/unix-domain-sockets-vs-tcp-sockets/)

Comment: The thing is that i am configuring graphite to use memcached.. which can only use tcp/ip sockets.

Answer (score -1):

querying to 127.0.0.1:11211 is better as compared to querying memcached on interface ip.

Comment: Please justify your answer with proper reasons

Comment: Not a complete answer - the question specifically asks "please explain why also".