# What's the difference in localhost vs 0.0.0.0?

Tags: linux

What's the difference in telling a service to run on `localhost:xxxx`, `127.0.0.1:xxxx` and `0.0.0.0:xxxx`?

I needed to use `0.0.0.0` to get another host to be able to connect to my service.

Answer (score 18):

127.0.0.1:xxxx is the normal loopback address, and localhost:xxxx is the hostname for 127.0.0.1:xxxx.

0.0.0.0 is slightly different, it's an address used to refer to all IP addresses on the same machine. Or no specific IP address.

Here's a stack exchange post that explains the difference in more detail [What's the difference between ip address 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1?](https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1)

Answer (score 4):

localhost is a special virtual network interface, just like your ethernet or wifi each have a special interface.

The difference is that localhost, being a network interface, is very specific. When you say that you want to connect to 127.0.0.1, you are connecting specifically to localhost. Just like you specify IP of your wifi/ethernet to connect to those interfaces.

0.0.0.0 however, is not really an interface and it means to just try and connect to *every* available interface. This will try and connect to all the available interfaces instead of just 127.0.0.1.

Hence two are different.

EDIT: This here probably explains it a lot better an in greater detail: https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0